# SVN log message of some revisions are missing

Tags: svn, logging

We are using SVN server 1.6.9 as our development repository. But from this week we found that logs of some revisions are missing:

```
$ svn log http://svn.mywork.com/svn/my_system/branches/A01 -l 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r675 | yin.su | 2012-11-14 10:21:03 +0800 (Wed, 14 Nov 2012) | 1 line

instant msg model impl 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r602 | svnsync | 2012-10-26 19:47:29 +0800 (Fri, 26 Oct 2012) | 1 line


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the log message of r602 is missing.
Further, we have tried to use "svn propget" to retrieve the log msg:

```
$ svn propget svn:log --revprop -r 602 http://svn.mywork.com/svn/my_system/branches/A01
```

Nothing returns then.

If we add PEG revison to the url, then the msg is returned:

```
$ svn propget svn:log --revprop -r 602 http://svn.mywork.com/svn/my_system/branches/A01@HEAD
This is my SVN log message
```

But adding PEG revision to url in "svn log" command doesn't work still.

In r602 we actually made a merge from branch B01 to A01 by using "svn merge" command. So we are confused why adding PEG revision to the propget cmd works, and why r602 log msg is missing from "svn log" cmd?

Thanks!

Comment: `svn proplist` please (without PEG-revisions) and `svn propget --xml`

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to commit Subversion revisions with no log messages or a log message consisting of a few spaces, just to get Subversion not to ask whether or not you want to commit without a log message:

```
$ svn commit -m" "
```

Are you sure there should be a log message?

Also, it's possible to use `svn pset` to completely remove a log message too. Do your users have the ability to use `svn pset --revprops`?

Try getting the output in `--xml` format. This way, you can see if the log message is really missing or if it's just a few spaces.

```
$ svn log --xml -v -r602 $REPO | less
```

Comment: David, thanks for your information! We are sure there is the log msg of the revision, because it can be obtained by: `svn log http://<parent url of the branch> -r <the_rev>`   So we use the branch url in "svn log" command there is no message returned, but if we use the PARENT url of the branch, then we can get the log message

Comment: Unlike other version control systems messages are part of the _revision_ and not individual files. What happens if you use the `-v` flag too? Do you see the files that are in that revision?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for returning back late!
The issue was finally solved. The root cause was the mis-config of Apache authentication!

The phenomena is that only the merging log msg were missing, so I tried to take a look at the Apache access log, and found this:

```
10.14.21.75 - - [22/Nov/2012:13:22:05 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/opencore/branches/ali00304473_Other_20120426_opencore HTTP/1.1" 200 192
10.14.21.75 - - [22/Nov/2012:13:22:05 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/opencore/branches/ali00304473_Other_20120426_opencore HTTP/1.1" 207 772
10.14.21.75 - - [22/Nov/2012:13:22:05 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/opencore/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 1040
```

No username was identified in the requests! Then I found the SVN access rights for the branch was set to allow EVERYONE to read:

```
[opencore:/branches/ali00304473_Other_20120426_opencore]
* = r
```

Furthermore, in `httpd.conf`, it was configured like this:

```
<Location /svn/>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /home/admin/svnroot
        AuthBasicProvider file ldap
        AuthType Basic
        .....
        AuthUserFile /home/admin/svnfiles/svn-auth-file
        Satisfy Any
        Require valid-user
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/admin/svnfiles/svn-access-file
</Location>
```

So either changing "`* = r" to "* =`" in the SVN access file, or updating "Satisfy Any" to "Satisfy All" will fix the problem.

Conclusion:
In our previous config (bad config), when a SVN HTTP request (without auth info) comes to the server, it first handled by Apache httpd. Because httpd was configured as "Satisfy Any", so "Require valid-user" is not a necessary option, so the request was forwarded to MOD_SVN. As the branch was opened to every one (* = r), so MOD_SVN didn't rise the authentication request back to SVN client, it then tried to fetch the logs from repository. But fetching SVN log requires authentication/authorization token, so MOD_SVN just silently failed inside the module, and httpd just returned empty log message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The entry from the FAQ below is worth a read because it's not the behaviour I'd expect from svn log.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/server-l10n/www/faq.html#hidden-log

**I cannot see the log entry for the file I just committed. Why?**

Assume you run 'svn checkout' on a repository and receive a working copy at revision 7 (aka, r7) with one file in it called foo.c. You modify the file and commit it successfully. Two things happen:

```
The repository moves to r8 on the server.
In your working copy, only the file foo.c moves to r8. The rest of your working copy remains at r7.
```

You now have what is known as a mixed revision working copy. One file is at r8, but all other files remain at r7 until they too are committed, or until 'svn update' is run.

```
   $ svn -v status
   7        7 nesscg       .
   8        8 nesscg       foo.c
   $
```

If you run the 'svn log' command without any arguments, it prints the log information for the current directory (named '.' in the above listing). Since the directory itself is still at r7, you do not see the log information for r8.

To see the latest logs, do one of the following:

```
Run 'svn log -rHEAD'.
Run 'svn log URL', where URL is the repository URL.
Ask for just that file's log information, by running 'svn log foo.c'.
Update your working copy so it's all at r8, then run 'svn log'.
```